# port of turtlebot_navigation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I want to port the turtlebot_navigation stack to a robot called eddie,
which it uses the turtlebot API to use it under ros which is the follwing:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/eddiebot

After successfully running that package I have 2 basic nodes running:
minimal.launch
kinect.launch

this is the stack for the turtlebot navigation (which is needed for SLAM):
http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation?distro=groovy

which has the following dependencies:

Dependencies (3)

```
gmapping
move_base
turtlebot_bringup
```

In our case we already have the turtlebot_bringup. and I think the "gmapping" package is a generic one so it doesn't needs to be modify if I'm correct. The problem is that the move_base package needs to be made for the eddiebot,

so I was going to ask you what do I need to do to get this package running?

Thanks,
Omar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58956/port-of-turtlebot_navigation/) by [konet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4438/konet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are tutorials on setting up the Navigation stack on a new robot: http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup (move_base is simply the central part of the navigation stack). Those tutorials will pretty much explain what each configuration file in turtlebot_navigation is doing.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1